# Xcode 8 GM seed distribution profile not set automatically

Tags: ios, xcode8

My existing iOS Project Developer Profile set automatically in Xcode 8 GM seed.

But Xcode 8 GM seed distribution profile not get set automatically.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this [WWDC video](http://Check%20out%20What's%20New%20in%20Xcode%20App%20Signing%20from%20#WWDC%202016%20https://developer.apple.com/wwdc16/401) it might help you find the answer